# writing a regex which is working pretty well

Tags: regex

I have written a regex query to extract a URL. Sample text:

```
<p>a tinyurl here <a href="https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU">https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU</a></p>
```

URL I need to extract:

```
https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU
```

My regex attempts:

1. ```
   https:\/\/vvvconf.[a-z].*\/x\/[a-zA-z0-9]*
   ```

   This extracts:

   ```
   {"https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU">https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU"}
   ```
2. ```
   >https:\/\/vvvconf.[a-z].*\/x\/[a-zA-z0-9]*<
   ```

   This extracts:

   ```
   {">https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU<"}
   ```

How can I refine the regex so I just extract the URL `https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU`?

Comment: Tip: Parse HTML with an HTML parser. Using a regular expression is not the way to crack this nut.

Comment: For the example data you could make the dot non greedy `.*?` but try using a parser if available. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @tadman I need to do this as a part of extracting data from a database column, so I am not using HTML parser.

Comment: Just use `https:\/\/vvvconf.[a-z].*\/x\/\w+` then.

Comment: @VikG, if the database column contains HTML, why _not_ use an HTML parser?

Comment: please rewrite your question heading as a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you want to extract the URL from the `href` attribute, or the text within the `a` tag. Assuming the latter you can use a positive lookbehind (if your regex flavor supports it)

```js
const input = '<p>a tinyurl here <a href="https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU">https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU</a></p>';
const regex = /(?<=[>])https:[^<]*/;
console.log(input.match(regex))
```

Output:

```
[
  "https://vvvconf.instenv.atl-test.space/x/HQAU"
]
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=[>])` - positive lookbehind for `>` (expects but excludes `>`)
- `https:` - expect start of URL (add as much as desired)
- `[^<]*` - scan over everything that is not `<`